# Implementing Periodic Location Updates in iOS even if app gets terminated

Tags: ios, swift, cllocationmanager

My application requires periodic location updates (every 10 minutes). In foreground and background (app not terminated) the application is working correctly. But the problem starts to occur when the app is terminated by the user.

I tried using this tutorial http://mobileoop.com/getting-location-updates-for-ios-7-and-8-when-the-app-is-killedterminatedsuspended .
It works only when user's location is changing because of **startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges**. But I need locations in terminated state even if user is not changing its location.

Also, I have tried most of the stackoverflow questions but most of them gets satisfied with **startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges**. But in my case it won't be enough to fulfil the application needs.

Comment: Then you need a jailbreak or a different platform...

Comment: @Wain Can I use timers to run in background and use start and stop updating the location using location manager? But at the same time, it runs even after the app gets terminated with same interval.

Comment: No, you can not do what you ask for.

Comment: Can you plz post your location service code and the way you are trying to track it?

Comment: @AnkitSingh: for your knowledge, please check that does timers can run in background or not? Actually, they can't. They can only work in foreground

Comment: In iOS, once you force kill the app, then there is no way to do anything. User have to restart the app. It is not an Android. If you still wants it then jailbreaking is only way. And in jailbreak, for keeping any task always running, you dont have to tweak in given app but you have to tweak in system springboard(all SB classes).

Comment: As the others have said, no way around having updates when the app is terminated *unless* startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges is called, however this answer probably is probably the optimal one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44371982/3164070

Answer (score 1):

If a user terminates the app the system no longer grants it the same privileges. Background fetch operations and background location will not get executed until the user decides to start up your app again. The system recognizes this a user choice to not have this app running in any way again.

This isn't like the world of Android where an app can do as it pleases. Apple prefers user choice over what an app developer wants. This is of course good and bad as a developer. You need to provide the user with useful information about what your app is doing in the background so that they will allow it to run without terminating it. If they do terminate it, there is nothing that you can do.