# Receiving Location even when app is not running in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, geolocation

Still very new to Swift. I have come from an Android background where there is BroadcastReceiver that can deliver location info to a service even though the app isn't running.

So I was looking for something similar in iOS/Swift and it appears that before this wasn't possible but it may be now. I am developing for iOS 10 but would be great if it was backwards compatible.

I found

```
startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges
```

which I can execute to start delivering location updates, although this raises a few questions. Once I call this and my app is NOT running, are the updates still being sent ? And how would the app wake up to respond ?

Also restarting the phone and when it return, does this mean I still need call startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges again meaning that I would have to wait for the user to execute my app. Or does it remember the setting after reboot ?

Still a little confused how to get around this, here's a brief explanation of what I am trying to do.

I would like to update the location of the phone even though the app is not running, this would be sent to a rest service every so often.

This way on the backend services I could determine if somebody is within X meters of somebody also and send them a push notification.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

It may or may not be a good solution but if I were you I would have used both `startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges` and `regionMonitoring`.

[Here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/19Ih1mU17XQn_SoyujtmW-uZTBt5mLCXj/view) is the sample I made which worked well with iOS 13.

Lets take `regionMonitoring` first. We have certainly no problems when the app is in foreground state and we can use the **CLLocationManager's** `didUpdate` delegate to get the location and send it to the server.

Keep latest current location in AppDelegate's property, lets say:

```
var lastLocation:CLLocation?

//And a location manager
var locationManager = CLLocationManager()
```

We have two `UIApplicationDelegates`

```
func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {
    //Create a region
}

func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {
    //Create a region
}
```

So whenever the user kills the app or makes the app go to background, we can certainly create a region around the latest current location fetched. Here is an example to create a region.

```
func createRegion(location:CLLocation?) {

    if CLLocationManager.isMonitoringAvailable(for: CLCircularRegion.self) {
            let coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake((location?.coordinate.latitude)!, (location?.coordinate.longitude)!)
            let regionRadius = 50.0

            let region = CLCircularRegion(center: CLLocationCoordinate2D(
                latitude: coordinate.latitude,
                longitude: coordinate.longitude),
                                          radius: regionRadius,
                                          identifier: "aabb")

            region.notifyOnExit = true
            region.notifyOnEntry = true

            //Send your fetched location to server

            //Stop your location manager for updating location and start regionMonitoring
            self.locationManager?.stopUpdatingLocation()
            self.locationManager?.startMonitoring(for: region)
        }
        else {
            print("System can't track regions")
        }
    }
```

Make use of RegionDelegates

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didEnterRegion region: CLRegion) {
    print("Entered Region")
}

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didExitRegion region: CLRegion) {
    print("Exited Region")

    locationManager?.stopMonitoring(for: region)

    //Start location manager and fetch current location
    locationManager?.startUpdatingLocation()
}
```

Grab the location from `didUpdate` method

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {

    if UIApplication.shared.applicationState == .active {
    } else {
        //App is in BG/ Killed or suspended state
        //send location to server
        // create a New Region with current fetched location
        let location = locations.last
        lastLocation = location

        //Make region and again the same cycle continues.
        self.createRegion(location: lastLocation)
    }
}
```

Here I have made a 50m region radius circle. I have tested this and it is called generally after crossing 100m from your center point.

Now the second approach can me using `significantLocationChanges`

On making the app go background or terminated, we can just stop location manager for further updating locations and can call the `startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges`

```
self.locationManager?.stopUpdatingLocation()
self.locationManager?.startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges()
```

When the app is killed, the location is grabbed from `didFinishLaunching` method's `launchOptions?[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey.location]`

```
if launchOptions?[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey.location] != nil {
    //You have a location when app is in killed/ not running state
}
```

Make sure to keep **BackgroundModes** On for **Location Updates**
[image]

Also make sure to ask for `locationManager?.requestAlwaysAuthorization()` by using the key

```
<key>NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
    <string>Allow location</string>
```

in your **Info.plist**

There can be a third solution by taking **2 LocationManagers** simultaneously.

1. For region
2. Significant Location Changes

As using `significantLocationChanges`

> Apps can expect a notification as soon as the device moves 500 meters
>   or more from its previous notification. It should not expect
>   notifications more frequently than once every five minutes. If the
>   device is able to retrieve data from the network, the location manager
>   is much more likely to deliver notifications in a timely manner.

as per the give [Apple Doc](https://developer.apple.com/reference/corelocation/cllocationmanager/1423531-startmonitoringsignificantlocati)

So it totally depends on your requirements as the location fetching depends on many factors like the number of apps opened, battery power, signal strength etc when the app is not running.

Also keep in mind to always setup a region with good accuracy.

I know that this will not solve your problem completely but you will get an idea to move forward as per your requirements.

Comment: This is great! Super thanks. 1. Why do you have `notifyOnEntry` & `notifyOnExit` both set to `true`? Don't you need just one? 2. If app is launched (after being terminated) the you sure can `startUpdateLocations`. However the problem I've faced is that when app is in background or is suspended you'll get the `didEnterRegion`/`didExitRegion` callback. But since you're in the background I don't think you'd be able to do successfully being `startUpdateLocations`? It just never happens

Comment: For the point 1 we can have just `notifyOnExit` true, no need for the other one. For 2 point, if you are launching the app then we can do anything. Why will it cannot `startUpdateLocations`. By launching app you are making it in foreground and anything can be done in foreground I believe. The enter,exit region will be called in terminated state too. The updateLocations are called in background too when the region is exited as per my findings. Rest the details, exceptions and limitations are there in the answer

Comment: Agreed about launching. But to launch you must be terminated. My question is specifically about: when you all the following notes are true together: a) app is **not** terminated nor is foreground (ie your background/suspended) b) for *whatever* reason, either your system or yourself has done `stopUpdatingLocation()` c) you exit a region and get `didExitRegion` callback. In this state calling `startUpdatingLocation` will NOT WORK. Because you **can't** start tracking location in the background (you're only allowed to do `startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges` OR create a region in bckgrnd).

Comment: App isn't terminated, we go to BG and intentionally stop the location updates and create a region and on exit of region I call startUpdate. This is actually what is written in answer. I am not sure about whether on exitRegion, did it goes to the `didUpdate` delegate. If no, then the startUpdateLocation works fine as I am creating a new region in `didUpdate` delegate. If yes, then I need to again look into it.

Comment: What does "If no, then the startUpdateLocation works fine as I am creating a new region in didUpdate delegate" means? It's a simple question ARE YOU SURE if calling `startUpdatingLocation` works when all the a,b,c conditions are true? Even the [WWDC](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/716/?time=390) is confusing. This is from their Transcript of Session716: "So if you have background runtime for some reason, and you decide to start a location session, you might get some updates, but you **might** also get suspended before you receive all the information you had hoped to receive."

Comment: @Honey I have made a sample and did some logging. Here is the sample link: https://www.dropbox.com/s/lxddrsy4emnh4be/SampleLocation.zip?dl=0 . Here is the logFile link though it is in the container too of the project: https://www.dropbox.com/s/h8gi39wk7c71iar/LocationLogs.txt?dl=0

Kept your all  a,b,c conditions true. 1.Took app to background. 2. Intentionally stopped the location updates and created a region. 3. Received a call back in `didExit` and again started the location updates. I received another location in `didUpdate`. Any other point you noticed? Still to watch WWDC link video.

Comment: the app was in background all the time.

Comment: SUPER THANKS. I'm trying to use `os.log` so I can see the logs using mac console. I don't know how/where your logger works. But very likely you've proved me wrong. Also why are you doing `createRegion` inside your `didUpdateLocation`? Aren't you already doing that if app has `DIdEnterBackground` or `WillTerminate`? FWIW I `startupadtingLocations` inside `locationManagerDidPauseLocationUpdates` but that didn't work. Anyhow let me modify your code and get back to you later (it's midnight here:D )

Comment: @Honey In order to see the log file, download the zip file and make it run on device. Then keep the app in background. Go have a walk of 1 km. Come back and plug your device, open Xcode and click on Window menu of Xcode on top. Click on Devices, choose your device and download the container and save it somewhere. Go to the saved location of container and then right click and click on `Show Package Contents`.There you can see the Document Path, and inside the path I have made a Location directory where you can see your log file LocationLogs.txt, Open it and have a look. Time is is UTC in file.

Comment: See the check in `didUpdate`, only if the app is not active then it creates a region in `didUpdate` otherwise not. So whenever in BG, `didUpdate` is called, it will create a region. It will never create a region when you come back to foreground.

Comment: "whenever in BG, didUpdate is called, it will create a region." <-- Why are you creating a region when you're tracking (through didUpdateLocation)!? Shouldn't only create a region when you're not tracking

Comment: Exactly, but what I thought is that you are only tracking whenever the app is in FG. So I assumed whenever the app is in state other than FG, region creation is the best choice in order to save battery etc. We never get a callback or delegate when the app gets suspended. So, its best to create a region in BG or  in `willTerminate`.

Comment: but you could potentially be in the background for 5hrs and constantly be creating (unnessary) regions this way right?

Comment: @Honey App can never be in BG for 5 hours unless we are using VOIP or playing a music etc. It will move to suspended state, though the instance will be always present in your app switcher. We never create unnecessary regions as per my code. A region is only created whenever you cross an older region. So, just 1 region at a time as per my code. You can also delete regions created by writing the delete code when you move to foreground or `didBecomeActive`

Comment: I think it can be in the background for 5hrs or more if either 1.  you're constantly moving 2. you just set `pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically` to `false` so app would stay in background until it drains your battery right?

Comment: By default `pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically` is `true`. Yes, constantly moving will drain the battery as it also happens in `Maps` or `Google Maps` apps too. But you can never know when your app gets suspended or the OS might interfere and suspends it and prioritise other apps. I am afraid, but I don't have a full proof answer to it.

Comment: Hey, I just a very related conversation. It thought you might be interested in: See [this chat discussion](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150127/discussion-between-paulw11-and-honey)

Comment: Hi, I'm updating the user's location in the firestore, and it's working fine when the app is in foreground and background mode but this isn't working when the application is terminated. Can you help me with that?

Comment: @HeenaBeriya Here is the updated sample which I made and tested on iOS 13.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/19Ih1mU17XQn_SoyujtmW-uZTBt5mLCXj/view?usp=sharing

There in containers, you can also find the log file. You can download the container and see the text file as well. I am logging all entries in a text file

Comment: Is createRegion and location notification a must?

Comment: @Bagusflyer No. Notifications were only kept for debugging purposes. You can just log into a text file.