# Location updates in background mode for iOS 10 not working [Swift 3.0 - Xcode 8]

Tags: swift, xcode, background, ios10, cllocation

I'm having trouble trying to update the location consistently (in the background) for my app using iOS 10. It works perfectly on the simulator, But doesn't work at all on devices. I've read a lot of questions here. But I still cannot find an answer. Most people with the same problem lean towards it being a problem with Apple's iOS 10 software, but I doubt that could be the issue.

I've set up the background capabilities and info.plist i.e "Privacy - Location 
When in Use Usage Description". And I've added the below commands. But it still doesn't work on my test device (iPhone 7 running iOS 10).

```
    manager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest        
    manager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    manager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
    manager.startUpdatingLocation()
    manager.allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates = true
    manager.pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically = false
```

Can someone please help? This is one of the last issues I need to solve for one of my projects. 
Any links or working Github projects would be greatly appreciated! I just cant figure this one out!

Comment: You have to set the background capability for your target to permit location updates. That’s not the same as the privacy setting, which you also have to do. Or just use significant change service.

Comment: First of all, simulator and device, both are two very different things. Only device testing will guarantee you real results. Secondly, have a look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/44371982/2545465

Comment: Is this all running in the appdelegate?