# Is that possible to receive Location even when app is not running in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, background, cllocationmanager

I am making an app that trace all the trips made by a user.
The app works perfectly when it is in background or in foreground but I am looking for a way to get it worked even if the app is not running.

I followed exactly this answer : [Receiving Location even when app is not running in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44369117/receiving-location-even-when-app-is-not-running-in-swift)

But this doesn't work as expected.

I have two property in my AppDelegate

```
var lastLocation:CLLocation?
//And a location manager
var locationManager = CLLocationManager()
```

In my DidFinishLaunchingWithOptions I configure the CLLocationManager

```
 locationManager.delegate = self
 locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
 locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters
```

In my applicationWillTerminate :

```
lastLocation = HomeController.locations.last 
createRegion(location: lastLocation)
```

Here is the rest :

```
func createRegion(location:CLLocation?) {

    if CLLocationManager.isMonitoringAvailable(for: CLCircularRegion.self) {
        let coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake((location?.coordinate.latitude)!, (location?.coordinate.longitude)!)
        let regionRadius = 50.0

        let region = CLCircularRegion(center: CLLocationCoordinate2D(
            latitude: coordinate.latitude,
            longitude: coordinate.longitude),
            radius: regionRadius,
            identifier: "aabb")

        region.notifyOnExit = true
        region.notifyOnEntry = true

        //Send your fetched location to server
        UserDefaults.standard.set(UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "nbLocNotrunning") + 1, forKey: "nbLocNotrunning")
        //Stop your location manager for updating location and start regionMonitoring
        self.locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
        self.locationManager.startMonitoring(for: region)
    } else {
        print("System can't track regions")
    }
}

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didEnterRegion region: CLRegion) {
    print("Entered Region")
}

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didExitRegion region: CLRegion) {
    print("Exited Region")

    locationManager.stopMonitoring(for: region)

    //Start location manager and fetch current location
    locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
}

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {

    if UIApplication.shared.applicationState != .inactive {
    } else {
        //App is in BG/ Killed or suspended state
        //send location to server
        // create a New Region with current fetched location
        let location = locations.last
        lastLocation = location

        //Make region and again the same cycle continues.
        self.createRegion(location: lastLocation)
    }
}
```

I wonder where the mistake can come from and why I never enter in the function didExitRegion.
For now, I just increment a variable in UserDefaut "nbLocNotrunning" in order to know how many times I leave a region but this number never increase when I stop my app.

Comment: Have you looked into iOS's background modes? I don't believe it is possible to monitor a user's location constantly while the app is not running, that would kill the battery pretty quickly. You can however periodically do some work as background fetch

Comment: Yeah I heard about background fetch, but does it allow me to get the user location like every 100 meter or every x minutes ?

Comment: You can specify a desired update interval, but it's up to the system to determine if it actually runs your fetching code so I wouldn't rely on that